# How to set <input> border

Tags: html, css

I am not sure how to call this kind of feature but my question is, is there a way to set the color of the following effect:

[image]

Using just `border` doesn't make it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [the `outline` property](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/outline.html):

```
input:focus { outline: 2px orange solid }
```

`outline` works in all modern browsers [except for IE < 8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

The `:focus` pseudo-class works in all modern browsers except IE - you would have to use a JavaScript workaround for that as shown [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fixing-focus-in-internet-explorer/).

However, you will not be able to duplicate the desired effect (which seems to be Chrome's default behaviour when focusing on a field?) entirely because `outline` doesn't have a `radius` property. Maybe @Sarfraz' suggestion is a suitable workaround for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this css:

```
input:focus,textarea:focus,select:focus{
    border:1px solid #fafafa;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px #007eff;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #007eff;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #007eff;
}
```

### [Check out the demo](http://jsbin.com/exihi4)

off course you can change the color as you like.